# Using State with HTMLElement with createSlice from Redux Toolkit

Tags: redux-toolkit

When trying to create a reducer whose state contains a key that is of type HTMLDivElement (or any other HTMLElement derivative), I get an `Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type` for what seems to be all of the keys of the HTMLElement.

```
interface ITestEvent {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  ref: HTMLDivElement;
}

interface AddEventPayload {
  event: ITestEvent;
}

interface TestEventState {
  events: ITestEvent[];
}

const initialState: TestEventState = {
  events: [],
};

const testSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addEvent(state, action: PayloadAction<AddEventPayload>) {
      state.events.push(action.payload.event); // Error here
    },
  },
});
```

Below is a typescript playground link illustrating the issue.

[https://typescriptlang.org/play link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC+cAZlBCDgByAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgNwBYAFAHgbbFB4YicAJIAVNHJgBRAG5oTiA3DhsMINAC44ByhjAHM9fS9gOkDgsIivdB5AgAkbAFkAGQARYGdHPDQ-EwjOAyMTNDMLNDgGOjoXNxgKalo6D0i4NFcTQNt7J16YUvL9Y1NzSzsHJpMcGCxahE9u4bl+maHmgG0AXVHDfWR2BzhjTWAMPAWlwK25mFvsOABeTq8e5o24feIDTgRAwnNhnbAOfCEWrvVCYbCQogAChWXR8fkCQnBWn+XQuLGuzxIq3EEiIUB+KK8XnojWGiIcS1IFhY7ECrRo9CYLLYAB56rTmuz2gA+ACUHypXgZ2AAdF8THIZWAJHIABaI5msNhKqgcuhy4aihJUzg4rymgFGgxAA)

The same happens when creating a reducer via createReducer.

Is this a limitation of TypeScript in some way/is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with the `immer` type `Draft`.

`Draft<typeof initialState>` seems to end up with something slightly different than the original `Event` type in there.

But generally, this is advised against and will probably also lead to runtime issues and maybe even the redux devtools crashing when they try to display that event.

It is only ever advised to put serializable normal objects into the state:
https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions